# Display D3 graph with ember

Tags: ember.js, d3.js

Could anybody explain how to render a simple line graph with d3 and ember, using ember-data for the models.
The graph should rerender when the underlying model changes.

I found the following jsfiddle: *"removed link to be able to post solution"* , but don't understand how it works.
How should it be adapted for example, to use a real ember-data model.
Something like:

```
App.Point = DS.Model.extend({
    x: DS.attr("number"),
    y: DS.attr("number")
});
```

**update:**

Intuitivepixel cleaned and modernized the example. I've also added some dummy fixture data: http://jsbin.com/abadom/11/edit
The problem now seems to be that the randomly generated values still are rendered, instead of the fixture data.

**update 2:**

After help from some people on IRC, this does what I wanted: http://jsbin.com/abadom/35/edit

Comment: Working from the example, you could replace function `generateNewChartValues`, with an ajax request to your server that returns y values for the chart. To make it work with points, like your model, you'd have to modify how the view functions `didInsertElement` and `updateChart` work with the underlying content property; instead of being an array of y values, the content property would presumably be an array of "points".

Comment: Suppose there is a PointController (and route?), could you explain how I would access that data (controller.content) in the ChartView?

Comment: The content of the ChartView is already bound to the `App.chartValuesController`; see in the ApplicationView `chartValuesBinding: 'App.chartValuesController.content'` and in the template `{{view App.ChartView contentBinding="view.chartValues"}}`. Set the content of chartValuesController with an ajax request to your points route.

Comment: Just a heads-up if you didn't already know: Netflix have [Ember-NF-Graph](https://github.com/Netflix/ember-nf-graph) (a DSL on top of required D3) and there's also the newer [Ember E3](https://github.com/RavelLaw/e3) which is simpler, borrows some from D3 but doesn't require it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not be a full solution, but following the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/2UPLp/16/light/) you mentioned I've refactored the code a little, so that it uses `ember-data` models. I've also updated all the js dependencies to the latest versions to proof that it still works. I guess you have now a better starting point on using `ember-data`'s model together with **d3** and still following `ember`'s conventions.

Have a look at this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ifarof/1/edit), you maybe find it useful.

**Edit**

Since you where asking for routes in your comments, see here another updated [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ifarof/9/edit) *with routes*. It still uses random values *(for the sake of simplicity)*, but you can see the data changing by navigation trough the routes etc.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that's already much more understandable. Just a last question, suppose that the ChartValue comes from some store, maybe via fixtures or via a call to a json api. I'd normally do something like return App.ChartValue.find() in a ChartValueRoute, but there is no route here. And then the values could be accessed with a `controllers.chartvalue.content` or something similar?

Comment: See this updated jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ifarof/4/edit I've added a `ApplicationRoute` where the model hook returns, well, still the randomValues, but it could be anything like `App.ChartValues.find()` if you had Fixtures for example, then in your template you could bind the view's content like this: `{{view App.ChartView contentBinding="model"}}`

Comment: I've updated the jsbin (http://jsbin.com/abadom/7/edit) with fixtures, but now graph doesn't render anymore. I suspect this is because content isn't an array and `content.length` returns undefined. How would you iterate over it?

Comment: It also looks like I did something wrong and the data is still the randomly generated stuff instead of the fixtures: http://jsbin.com/abadom/11/edit